# DataGridView cómo chequear si una cell está vacía?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando un programa que contiene un DataGridView dentro de un formulario, y estoy importando datos a este DataGridView desde un archivo XML.
Dentro de este DataGridView, puedo agregar, editar y eliminar estos datos y guardar estos cambios en el archivo XML cuando se hace clic en un botón. (Hay dos columnas.)
Mi problema aquí es que necesito comprobar si alguna cell está vacía cuando se hace clic en el botón, y en ese caso, mostrar un MessageBox que indique esto y no me deje guardar estos cambios.

He intentado for loops y más, y no pude encontrar nada útil.
¡Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme! Gracias

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Sullair
{
public partial class IPs : Form
{
    public IPs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void IPs_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\Administrador\source\repos\Sullair\schema.xml");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        DataTable db = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        db.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\Administrador\source\repos\Sullair\schema.xml");
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Save();   
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Una opción es investigar cómo puedes recorrer las filas del DataGridView. [Ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737522/4092887). `He intentado for loops y más, y no pude encontrar nada útil` = agrega lo que hayas intentado.

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar como agregas, editas o eliminas registros del datagridview por lo que comentas eso ya lo tienes, quizá solo falte realizar validaciones en esa parte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Joaco,

Puedes probar algo como esto:

```
if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
{
   bool bCampoVacio = false;
   foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
       {
           if (dc.Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dc.Value.ToString()))
           {
               bCampoVacio = true;
           }
       }
   }
   if (bCampoVacio)
      MessageBox.Show("Hay algún campo vacío!");
}
```

En éste código recorres todas las `Rows` de la `dataGridView1` y dentro del `foreach` de las `Rows`, recorres todas las `Cells` de esa misma `Row` comprobando si hay alguna celda sin contenido.

Comment: Hola! El código va bien. El único problema que está sucediendo, es que el DataGridView crea automáticamente una fila vacía en la parte de abajo para poder insertar nuevos valores, y el código está contando esa fila también, lo cual no debería suceder. Hay alguna manera de contemplar eso?

Comment: Aquí tienes 2 opciones:
1. Si no tienes que dejar insertar ninguna fila mas a la `DataGridView` puedes desactivar la opción de poder añadir líneas nuevas poniendo `AllowUserToAddRows = false`.
2. Reemplazar el foreach por un for y contar asta el rowcount -1:
`for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount -1; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells)
             {
   
             }
            }`

Comment: Si, en la `DataGridView` se deben poder insertar nuevas filas, sólo no dejar guardar los cambios si es que hay algún campo sin completar. Voy a probar la 2da opción a ver si funciona. Gracias!

Comment: En el código que te he puesto sería con un `dataGridView1.RowCount -2` y no `-1` ya que empieza desde el 0 y tendrías que evitar la última fila de la Grid.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, antes había probado un código muy parecido pero lo has podido completar perfectament. Te agradezco muchísimo! Saludos